# Async function always returns the same data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, axios

I have a screen with fetching product data. "getProductById" is called once when screen is mounted.

```
const getProductById = async ({ productId }: { productId: string }) => {

    const response = await productsService.getProductById({ id: productId })
    if (response.isOk && response.data) {
      setProduct(response.data)
      console.log('response product: ', response.data)
    }

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductById({ productId })
  }, [])
```

Also there is a "like" function called when button is pressed. First, I update like status and again try to fetch product data to refresh screen:

```
  const onLike = async () => {

    await productsService.setLikeStatus({
      isLiked: true,
      itemId: product.items_id,
    })

    getProductById({ productId })
  }
```

"getProductById" returns correct data on screen mount but after pressing like button, it stills returns the same data as the first time (is_liked = false) even though I can see that the product like status has been updated in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

What's also weird is that I added another button that calls "getProductById" just for testing purposes. When I hit that button after "like" request, it's still showing the old data in the console log. But if I give it a couple of minutes and hit it again, a new data (is_liked = true) is shown in console.

Comment: What happens if you add `await` to the last line of the onLike function?

Comment: What does `productsService.getProductById` do? Is it a GET request that is cached?

Comment: I was  gonna say it sounds like the api is being cached. Perhaps there’s a flag you can use to force a new fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass cache-control in header while fetch request

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');
```